# Pass variable to Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: search-engine, google-custom-search

Is it possible to pass a search variable into the Google Custom Search Engine that I have embedded on my website? I can get the search engine to work, but I can't pass it a term via POST (it's coming from a search button on other pages of the website)

I tried to hack the code I found here: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=search#hello_world

And this is what I have so far... ($q is the term I am passing to it)

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en'});

    function OnLoad()
    {
        var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('***my key****');
        customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
        customSearchControl.draw('cse');
        searchControl.execute("$q");
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, I know it's a crappy answer, but you've actually got it right apart from referencing the wrong variable name. Oh, also, as an aside, I would also hope you're doing some kind of sanitisation on $q, in case someone posted something like this to your form: term"); alert("aha!

```
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');
    searchControl.execute("$q");
```

should be:

```
    customSearchControl.draw('cse');
    customSearchControl.execute("$q");
```

Also, thank you for the question - I was looking for how to do this myself!

Comment: Thank you!! I've been pulling my hair out over this, and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This is to help anyone using PHP trying to accomplish this same goal. The example above uses...

```
customSearchControl.execute("$q");
```

to read the parameter being passes in. On a PHP site you would use...

```
customSearchControl.execute("<?php echo $_POST['your_paramter_name_here'];?>");
```

You could use $_GET or $_REQUEST if your parameter is not in the post.

Of course you should should sanitize the input first.  Something like this is pretty weak but it's a start...

```
customSearchControl.execute("<?php echo htmlentities( trim( $_POST['your_paramter_name_here'] ), ENT_QUOTES );?>");
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is looking for a bit more straight forward / simple solution. All you have to do is to pass search keywords into GET parameter named **q** (from your custom form into page where your GCS is), GCS will automatically use that search phrase.

Source: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

Comment: What a beautifully simply solution. ``site.com/search?q=query`` will automatilly search with that query. Thank you!